# How to draw that graph?

Tags: graph-theory

A specific set of graphs was given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872195/19341):

> Let $G$ be a 3-regular connected planar graph with a planar embedding where each face has degree either 4 or 6 and **each vertex is incident with exactly one face of degree 4**. Determine the number of vertices, edges and faces of degree 4 and 6.

For following set of equations was given as answer:

1. $2E=3n$
2. $2E=4F_4+6F_6$
3. $n-E+F_4+F_6=2$
4. $n=4F_4$

For bicubic planar graphs consisting of $4$- and $6$-faces only, $F_4=6$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1651869/19341)), so $n=4\cdot 6=24$ then $E=36$ and finally $F=14$. How does such a graph look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah I found it: [Truncated octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_octahedron);

[image]