# When are graphs $\Gamma_\mathfrak B$ gems?

Tags: graph-theory

> [Graph-theoretically, a map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_map_(graph_theory)#Graph-theoretical_approach) is a cubic graph ${\displaystyle \Gamma }$ with edges colored blue, yellow, red such that: $\Gamma$ is connected, every vertex is incident to one edge of each color, and cycles of edges not colored blue, have length 4.

So I wonder whether graphs  $\Gamma_\mathfrak B$ with the following properties

- bicubic
- planar
- with faces having 4 and 6 vertices only
- where the squares are separated (this is class 4 from this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1720727/19341))

can represents maps?

Planarity would guarantee a 3-edge coloring via the 4-color theorem.
I checked the planar drawing below which I thought it should be the [truncated octahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1652652/19341) and it didn't work. 
Reading further on Wikipedia:

> Note that $\Gamma$ is the flag graph or graph encoded map (GEM) of the map.

My question rephrased is: When are graphs  $\Gamma_\mathfrak B$ gems?

**EDIT** Looks like I've taken the wrong graph
[image]
which is **not** the truncated octaeder, but a [chamfered cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2301430/19341).

Comment: How does the truncated octahedron not work? See https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pabub.jpg

Comment: @Kundor sorry I got a little mixed up with ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every vertex must be in at least one square (since the red and yellow edges at the vertex must be part of a square), and it must be in exactly one square and two hexagons since you have specified that the squares are not adjacent.

So, we can build a cubic planar graph putting one square and two hexagons at each vertex; this forces us to make the graph of the truncated octahedron, so that's the only one.

Comment: ...and why does this construction not work for the chamfered cube?

Comment: @draks...: That's not a gem because not every vertex is in a square (many of the vertices are in three hexagons). The only cubic planar graph where every vertex is in one square and two hexagons is the truncated octahedron graph.

Comment: thanks... $ $$ $$ $