# The simplest $\Gamma_{\mathfrak B}$ graph where squares are separated by two hexagons...

Tags: graph-theory

Let's call a bicubic planar graph build up of faces having degree $4$ and $6$ only, a $\Gamma_{\mathfrak B}$ graph. The simplest one is the [truncated octahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1652652/19341).  Its planar drawing looks like the following:

[image]

Obviously every square is separated by at least one hexagon.

> What is the simplest $\Gamma_{\mathfrak B}$ graph where the squares are separated by at least **two** hexagons?

I found a way to extend it by traversing it in the following way (the sharp turns of the outmost edge are due to Paint and **not** vertices of degree $2$):
[image]

But it get's messy when I continue traversing, so I thought there is a way to simply expand a hexagon. Any idea welcome...

Comment: > every square is separated by at least one hexagon. Please clarify what does it mean.

Comment: @Smylic going from one square to another, you have to go through at least one hexagon...

Comment: How do you draw the diagrams in your question ? (What software do you use ?) ... I would call them trivalent planar graphs ... why do you use the word bicubic ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit that's just windows Paint. Trivalent is just cubic and bicubic means bipartite and cubic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture shows one example of 2 lines crossing the original graph and one round trip leaving all squares separated by at least 2 hexagons.

[image: example divided graph]

Comment: ugly, but correct...