# Six Octagons on a Surface with $\chi=-2$

Tags: graph-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Given a cubic bipartite graph $G$, living happily on an orientable surface with Euler characteristic $\chi$. Euler's formula then reads:
$$
F+V=E+\chi , 
$$
where $F=\sum f_k$, the number of $k$-gons. Now, let's restrict $G$ to $f_6$ hexagons and $f_8$ octagons only. Since its $3$-regularity it follows that:
$$
0\cdot f_6 -2 \cdot f_8=6\chi
$$
all along similar lines as given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1651869/19341)...

> How does the simplest non-trivial ($\chi=-2 \rightarrow f_8=6$) example look like?

Feel free to add as countably many hexagons, in case, you need them...

Comment: Looking at my construction again, it appears to have an octagon and four squares instead of three octagons. Sorry!

Comment: @MishaLavrov hmm but this doesn't work out on the double torus according to $2f_4-2f_8=-6$...strange...

Comment: I don't understand "a bipartite graph" on a surface. Can you give an example?

Comment: If you don't insist on bipartite, whatever it means, you can cover the double torus with exactly 6 octagons (and any number of hexagons) such that edges and vertices form a 3-regular graph.

Comment: This is forced by Euler's formula. On the other hand one can construct the graph with exactly 6 octagons and no hexagons. I' m not completely sure about the "any number of hexagons" part. Maybe there is a restriction on the number of hexagons. But there must always be exactly 6 octagons.

Comment: Bipartite means the vertices are 2-colorable. In other words, that every face has even degree.

Comment: @MishaLavrov can you verify my version of Euler's formula? Thanks...

Comment: Related: http://www.weddslist.com/groups/genus/2/8-3/8-3.php

Comment: @JoshB. Thanks for your link. It induced a [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3065865/19341)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]If you cover the double torus with only hexagons and octagons such that edges and vertices form a 3-regular graph, then you need exactly 6 octagons.

$$
f_6+f_8+(6f_6+8f_8)/3=(6f_6+8f_8)/2 +  \chi
$$
Since $\chi=-2$, we have $f_8=6$. 
From Euler's formula there is no restriction for the number of hexagons, but maybe there are geometric restrictions. The picture shows a covering with 6 octagons and no hexagon.

Comment: +1 very illustrative. Thanks. Concerning the octagons at the edge of the double torus (at the outside of the handles) it looks like that they split in two non connected squares, although the "face" is bounded by 8 vertices. Interesting... how does that relate to the linked stuff in [Josh's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3033651/three-octagons-on-a-surface-with-chi-2?noredirect=1#comment6303348_3033651)?

Comment: I don't see the squares. The regular maps in the link in Josh comment require the faces to be embedded,i.e. no self-intersection, so my covering is not a regular map.

Comment: Squares are the cycles of length 4 at the cutted handles. Thanks pointing out the difference to Josh...

Comment: Maybe you mean the 3 cycles?

Comment: Ah I thought that squares. But then I don't get how to form the fifth and sixth octagon...

Comment: The most left and the most right octagons have half circles that match the half circles of the 3 cycles

Answer (score 4):

Take two hexagonal lattices of torii. In each lattice, choose a hexagon, $h$, and then "glue" these two faces together into a new cycle $h*$.

Every vertex in $h*$ now has a degree of 4. To fix this, in $h*$, remove three edges of the same color. We get 3 new faces, $f'$, with $2\cdot(6-1)=10$ degrees.

No other faces or vertices were modified, so we arrive at a cubic graph with $\chi=-2$ composed only of hexagons and three 10-gons. By removing all the edges in $h*$, and then contracting all the vertices in $h*$, we get 6 octagons and hexagons everywhere else.

For a visual example, this is how you could create the 6 octagons part:

Start with two of these:

[image]

Then draw green edges connecting the highlighted (black) vertices in the previous picture, like so:

[image]

These faces with green edges all have degree 8. Elsewhere, each torus is unchanged, and should still have hexagons everywhere. Subdividing each green edge and adding there more edges can create 6 new hexagons and 3 10-gons.

Regarding your modified Euler's formula, it seems the $1+\chi$ part is wrong. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic), $\chi = V-E-F$. So using all your other work, $\sum (6-k)f_k = 6\chi$. This is consistent with what is known about polyhedra on the sphere.

Comment: Hmm since Henning didn't complain about my formula in the linked post I assume(d) it to be right...

Comment: Can you draw your construction?

Comment: I've added a visual aid, forgive me, but my artistic abilities are limited.

Comment: thanks for your contribution

Comment: Using your method one can obtain lattices with 6 octagons and $k=4,7,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,...$ hexagons. For $1,2,3,5,6,8,9$ or $12$ hexagons, I'm not sure if there are lattices.

Comment: @san in $\chi = 2$ you can have 6 squares and any number of hexagons except 1.

Comment: I suspect that in the present case you can have any number of hexagons, but your construction provides only the numbers above. There should be other constructions providing the rest of the numbers.

Comment: Stretching your method a little bit, one can get 6, 9 and 12 hexagons(together with 6 octagons). Do you know if the stuff for $\chi=2$ is published somewhere? Or at least written up?

Comment: It was mentioned by Grünbaum, I believe within his translation/summary of “Morphology Der Polymer” by Eherhard. It’s been a year at this point, I’ll try to find it.

Comment: Correction: I believe it was in one of his many papers on Eberhard-like theorems, either way, in the paper, I recall it taking no more than two sentences to mention. I think you can simply get the result that there does not exist a polyhedron with 1 hexagon by simply starting with one hexagon and maxing it cubic by adding squares

Comment: And how do you get for example 4 hexagons(and 6 squares)?

Comment: Turn two opposite faces of a cube into a column of three squares. Make these two columns be pointed orthogonal directions.

Comment: Nice. Is there a general method for doing this or is it just trial and error?

Comment: I do not know if the initial result was constructive or not.