# Count the number of sets of subsets of (Steiner?) triples

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-graph-theory, combinatorial-designs

Given a set of $v$ numbers. Fix $v$. How many sets of $v$ sorted triples can be created, matching the following conditions:

- two triples shall have atmost one number in common
- over all triples each number shall appear three times?

---

A representative example set of triples with $v=8$:
$$
S_A=(\color{red}1,\color{blue}2,\color{green}5)\;;\;S_B=(\color{blue}2,\color{grey}3,\color{purple}6)\;;\;S_C=(\color{grey}3,\color{pink}4,\color{orange}7)\;;\;S_D=(\color{red}1,\color{pink}4,8)
$$
$$
S_E=(\color{blue}2,\color{orange}7,8)\;;\;S_F=(\color{grey}3,\color{green}5,8)\;;\;S_G=(\color{pink}4,\color{green}5,\color{purple}6)\;;\;S_H=(\color{red}1,\color{purple}6,\color{orange}7)
$$

---

Can this be seen as $(v, b, r, k, λ)$ [block designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design)? When I read the definition there I find:

- $v(=8)$:   points, number of elements of X
- $b(=8)$:   number of blocks
- $r(=3)$:   number of blocks containing a given point
- $k(=3)$:   number of points in a block
- $\lambda(=1)$:   number of blocks containing any 2 distinct points

But obviously this doesn't fulfill the condition ${\displaystyle \lambda (v-1)=r(k-1)}$...

**UPDATE** My example looks like a subset of elements of the [Steiner Triple System](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerTripleSystem.html) $STS(9)$, where subsets that contain $9$ are omitted.

---

The question is motivated by bipartite cubic graphs. Bipartiteness forces $v=b$, cubicity asks for $r=k=3$. $\lambda =1 $ means that the graph is simple and has no squares.

The example above is derived from the graph shown [here](http://www.weddslist.com/groups/genus/2/8-3/8-3.php). It has 6 octagons living on a double torus. Black points are labelled with numbers $1$ to $6$; white points are labelled with characters $A$ to $H$.

Comment: Your definition is **not** equivalent to having a $\lambda=1$ in the design sense. Having $\lambda = 1$ would mean **every** pair of points would be contained in a unique block, in your example you have every pair of points contained in **at most** one block. I think this would sometimes be referred to as a partial design, or a $(v,v,3,3,\{0,1\})$ partial design.

Comment: @MorganRodgers partial design, I'll check that, thanks ...

Comment: The requirement that every pair (of triplets) contains *at most* 1 common number actually reminds me of codes, although the connection is loose enough that I'm not sure it helps..  A set meeting your requirement can be visualized as a  $v \times v$ binary matrix $A$, where each row is a number and each column is a triplet, and $A_{ij} = 1$ iff number $i$ is in triplet $j$.  By your requirements, every row and every column of this matrix has exactly three $1$s.  Now you can consider the rows as codewords.

Comment: (cont'd) The interesting thing is that these codewords are at least distance-4 apart, making them Single-Error-Correcting, Double-Error-Detecting (SECDED).  Such codes are in wide use, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code Hamming codes have a lot of symmetries, but I've never seen these studied in the context of restricting the codes words to each having exactly three bits being $1$.  So this connection may indeed be too loose to be useful.

Comment: @antkam interesting any way. Thanks. If you can find a reference to SECDED or working out the analogy: Worth an answer...